# Why doesn't text piped into an echo get outputted?

Tags: echo

Why doesn't this command output "1"?

```
echo 1 | echo
```

I imagine it working this way:

```
1. echo 1 (outputs 1)
2. | echo (takes the 1 as an input, then echos it)
```

Isn't this what should happen?

Answer (score 15):

echo doesn't use stdin, try using cat

```
echo 1 | cat
```

or

```
echo 1 | xargs echo
```